# How can I fetch the records with order by nested column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

**User**

- has_many :communities
- has_many :posts

**Community**

- belongs_to :user
- has_many :posts

**Post**

- belongs_to :user
- belongs_to :community

I'd like to show all the records of Posts at **example.com/posts**
But it has to be sorted by **Post owner User's 'last_signed_in'** column which is in Users table.

I tried this but this returns error **undefined method `users'**
How can I solve?

```
@orders = @community.posts.user.order("last_active_at ASC")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not call a user object on a collection of posts.

But you can include the users in your collection:

```
@community.posts.includes(:user).order("users.last_signed_in")
```

Further informations:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-multiple-associations

Comment: Thanks! But itt returns this error though. **Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'user.last_signed_in' in 'order clause': SELECT `posts....`** Indeed I have "last_signed_in" in Users table

Comment: Sorry I had a typo in the example code. The table must be 'users' instead of 'user'. I corrected it in the answer.